# Split a oracle table into multiple files using data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a table in oracle that i want to copy but its too big (2.4Gb) and i want to split this table into different files, for example, by year.
How can i implement this transformation through data factory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lookup` activity, `Foreach` activity, and `copy data` activity to load data to different files based on year.

1. Connect `lookup` activity to the oracle table and with query option write query to get the distinct years list from the table.
2. Pass the lookup output to `ForEach` activity and inside Foreach activity add `Copy` activity.
3. In [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties) source, connect to oracle table and use query option and add dynamic content to write query with filter using current item.

Ex: @concat(‘select * from tableName where = ’, item().columnname)

4. Connect copy activity sink to sink file and run the pipeline.
5. It generates a file for each loop with each year passed from lookup activity.